# Faster binary to decimal string conversion

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, boolean

Is there a faster way to convert a *Boolean* array to a decimal string other than this:

```
while (temp > 0)
{
    str = chars[(int)(temp % 10)] + str;
    temp /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Find the various ways you can achieve them and compare their speed and find how you can improve that. In this case, I'd use a `StringBuilder` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Convert.ToInt32() function.

```
string binaryString = "10001011";
string decimalString = Convert.ToInt32(binaryString,2).ToString();
```

Comment: I have a large Boolean array

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to just assume you have named your boolean array "arrBoolean". This answer takes inspiration from mmhasannn's answer, and may not necessarily be faster. But it fixes his answer not taking your Boolean array into consideration.

```
string binaryString = "";

for (int ii = 0; ii < arrBoolean.Length; ii++)
{
    if (arrBoolean[ii])
        binaryString += "1";
    else
        binaryString += "0";
}

string decimalString = Convert.ToInt32(binaryString, 2).ToString();
```

EDIT: Below is the updated answer, with regards to Krumia's suggestions. The above answer is kept for those who just prefers it.

```
StringBuilder binaryBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int ii = 0; ii < arrBoolean.Length; ii++)
{
    if (arrBoolean[ii])
        binaryBuilder.Append("1");
    else
        binaryBuilder.Append("0");
}

string decimalString = Convert.ToInt32(binaryBuilder.ToString(), 2).ToString();
```

References:

1. http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder

Comment: I would have used a `StringBuilder`, since he says he has "a _large_ `Boolean` array".

Comment: @Krumia Sorry it took me so long, but I just noticed your comment, and updated my answer accordingly.